# Import sass file from Dart package in Angular2 project

Tags: angular, sass, dart

I have an Angular2Dart project and am using the `ng_bootstrap` package. I am trying to access the bootstrap variables in my component's scss file. WebStorm's intellisense finds the variable, for example `$gray-dark`, but when the dart_sass_transformer runs, I get the error that the variable cannot be found. I thought I may need to `@import "package:ng_bootstrap/all";` into my component's scss file, but that also throws an error. Otherwise, I haven't had any problems using `ng_bootstrap`.

Here's the component's scss:

```
.message {
  font-size: 3em;
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: $gray-dark;
}
```

Here's the original builder error:

> Build error:
>   Transform Sass on integrations_web|lib/src/components/integration_overview/integration_overview_component.scss threw error: Undefined variable: "$gray-dark".
>           on line 28 of stdin 
>      color: $gray-dark;
>
> package:dart_sass_transformer/sass.dart 43  Sass.transform..

Here's the error from adding `@import "package:ng_bootstrap/all";` to the component's scss:

> Build error:
>   Transform Sass on integrations_web|lib/src/components/integration_overview/integration_overview_component.scss threw error: could not resolve import 'Instance of '_SassImport'' (tried [integrations_web|lib/src/components/integration_overview/package:ng_bootstrap/all.scss, integrations_web|lib/src/components/integration_overview/package:ng_bootstrap/all.sass, integrations_web|lib/src/components/integration_overview/package:ng_bootstrap/_all.scss, integrations_web|lib/src/components/integration_overview/package:ng_bootstrap/_all.sass])

Comment: What's the exact error? How are you compiling SASS? With a transformer? Try running `pub get --packages-dir` and then try again.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added more detail to the question. I am using `dart_sass_transformer` with `executable: sassc`. Running `pub get --packages-dir` did not change anything. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/transform_sass instead?